# Run a linux docker container on Windows Server 2022

Tags: docker, gcloud

I have a Windows Server 2022 running on GCP. I've installed docker as described here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers#docker_on_windows

Namely, I did this:

```
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force
Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider
Restart-Computer -Force
```

However, when I try to run a linux image, I get

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run busybox ls
Unable to find image 'busybox:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
docker: no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.20348 in the manifest list entries.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> docker run --rm --platform linux alpine ls
Unable to find image 'alpine:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: unsupported os linux.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit. I can't enable hyper-V on GCP. My processor is Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU @ 2.80GHz   2.80 GHz should't it allow nested virtualization

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWE5J.jpg)

Looks like I need to enable nested virtualization in gcp. For that, I need to set `enableNestedVirtualization` field to `true`. There are descriptions on how to do it with gcloud api, but no way I can get my customer to do that. Any way to do it either in the WebUI or the VPS itself?

Edit 2. Does this mean I can't run a linux docker container from Windows? Or is docker a special case?

> L1 VMs have the following restrictions:
> You must run Linux-based OSes; you can't use Windows Server images.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/nested-virtualization/overview

Comment: https://mountainss.wordpress.com/2022/05/28/running-ubuntu-and-debian-linux-distro-on-windows-server-2022-preview-with-wsl2/

Comment: thank you! I just edited my original question, looks like nested virtualization needs to be enabled before I can run hyper-v?

Answer (score 3):

So, a few things about what you are trying to do:

- Linux containers on Windows (either client 10/11 or Server) are not supported in production. You can run it for development/testing purposes.
- Linux containers require WSL to work on Windows. Specifically, for Windows Server 2022, WSL2 is required. I blogged about this here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/using-wsl-2-on-windows-server-2022-to-run-linux-containers/ba-p/3624745
- WSL 2 essentially runs a Linux VM and exposes the CLI and services. For that to work on any cloud, you need nested virtualization enabled.

Comment: Is there a way to run Docker on Windows 11 without Docker Desktop?

Comment: Not that I know of. Can you please clarify the scenario? Why do you want to run containers without Docker Desktop on Windows? Is it because of the cost? In that case, you could look into https://mobyproject.org/. Moby is the open source project from which Docker builds on. It's free, and community led.

Comment: Running older versions of Docker like 2.2